# wordcount not running in Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, cloudera

I have installed Cloudera 5.8 in a Linux RHEL 7.2 instance of Amazon EC2. I have logged in with SSH and I am trying to run the wordcount example for testing mapreduce operation with the following command:

```
 hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount archivo.txt output
```

The problem is that the wordcount program is blocked and it not produces the output. Only the following is prompted:

```
16/08/11 13:10:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-22-226.ec2.internal/172.31.22.226:8032

16/08/11 13:10:03 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1

16/08/11 13:10:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1

16/08/11 13:10:04 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1470929244097_0007

16/08/11 13:10:04 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1470929244097_0007

16/08/11 13:10:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-22-226.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1470929244097_0007/

16/08/11 13:10:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1470929244097_0007
```

And then get blocked since "Running job". After this I have to press Ctrl+C for unblock and it not produces the output.

Anyone that knows why?. I think it is probably a configuration issue and I am new to DataNodes and so on.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are no resources (map or reducer slots), job is waiting for resources. You can check the job status on.

```
http://ip-172-31-22-226.ec2.internal:8088
```

Comment: For browse that URL I have had to change the security group in EC2 dashboard to permit 8088 port. The result in that page is that I have 4 apps pending but 0 apps running, 0 completed. Why It could be?

Comment: As expected jobs are waiting for resources ... check the resource manager logs, you will find more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In google I can not find where the resource manager logs are. I have found the command for completed jobs ( yarn logs -applicationId applicationId) but not working for idle jobs... Please, where do you see the logs ??

Comment: Logs will be under <hadoop-home>/logs/yarn-resourcemanager*.log

Comment: Thanks again. I think the problem is about permissions. I have found hadoop logs within the path /var/log/. I have not found yarn logs in the yarn logs path but yes within /var/log/hadoop-mapreduce, in example. The log is called (roughly speaking) hadoop-cmf-yarn-JOBHISTORY-ip-172-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal.log.out. Within it I can see this line: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:8020/user/history/done]. It cannot create the "done" directory because it doesn't have permission. Any ideas?