# installing a previous version of Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

When I try to install a previous version of Cloudera with all packages(Cloudera Manager, CDH with all applications and so forth) through install manager binary always installs the lastest version of Cloudera (now 5.8) even if the manager installer bin was found in the Cloudera 5.4 directory in the repository. I want to install Cloudera 5.4. For that, I have found Cloudera 5.4 RPMs in the repository to install manually in RHEL but when I install them, yum finds dependency errors with the database and daemon packages perhaps because of a previous failure in the installation. Because of this I think this is not the best manner of install Cloudera 5.4. Anyone that knows how to install a previous version of Cloudera or have installed or have experience in that or can give me some advise on how to install it? Thanks!

Comment: Curious about your requirement for installing CDH 5.4, when CDH 5.8 is current?

Answer (score 1):

While, I'm not clear on why you would want an older version of CM, you can adjust your `cloudera-manager.repo` file to point to the specific version you want.  Something like this:

```
[cloudera-manager]
name = Cloudera Manager, Version 5.4.10
baseurl = https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5.4.10/
gpgkey = https://archive.cloudera.com/redhat/cdh/RPM-GPG-KEY-cloudera
gpgcheck = 1
```

Comment: I tried to install an older version of Cloudera because the wordcount was not running in Cloudera 5.8, please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902620/wordcount-not-running-in-cloudera/38910577?noredirect=1#comment65291723_38910577   .When I tried wordcount with the Cloudera VM with version 5.4 it works but my laptop have a limit of 4 GB of RAM and other applications of Cloudera did not work. Finally I have installed Cloudera 5.4.10 but I have the same problem, wordcount is not running... ¿Would you know why?. Please see the post and answer me something!! Thanks!!